# uglifyJS mangle props breaks with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, browserify, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I am trying to mangle property names Using UglifyJS. Whenever I include lodash into my code via `var _ = require('lodash')` I get the error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'`

This is a sample of my package.json file:

```
"build:6": "browserify ./test.js | uglifyjs --compress  --mangle --mangle-props reserved=[lodash,_,require,exports] > uglifiedbundle6.js"`
```

I thought that by reserving words such as `lodash` and `_` and `require` that I would be able to circumnavigate this issue, but it has been ineffective. Here is a test sample of code that breaks:

```
_ = require('lodash');

function testObj() {
    this.testProp1 = "one";
    this.testProp2 = 4;
}


var testLodash = _.reverse([1,2,3]);


testObj.prototype.testMethod = function(){}

var testVarOne = 1;
var testVarTwo = "two";
var testVarMethod = function(){}
var testObject = new testObj();

seven = testObject.testProp1 + testObject.testProp2 + testVarOne;
```

Comment: Is `lodash` actually installed?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, when the code is uglified, lodash gets concatenated and added to `uglifiedbundle6.js`